# Transfer between scopes in cmake

Tags: cmake, cmake-scopes

I do have a multi-component application, modeled with having one parent and two childs. The first one defines libraries, include files, etc.
The second one wants to use that information. How can I do that, without coding those names manually?

parent/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(MYNAME1 MyName1)
set(MYLINKNAME MyLinkName)
add_subdirectory(sub1)
message("Parent1: " ${MYNAME1} " " ${MYNAME2} " " ${MYNAME3} " " ${MYLINKNAME})
add_subdirectory(sub2)
message("Parent2: " ${MYNAME1} " " ${MYNAME2} " " ${MYNAME3} " " ${MYLINKNAME})
```

sub1/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(MYNAME1 MySub1 PARENT_SCOPE)
set(MYNAME2 MySub2 PARENT_SCOPE)
set(MYNAME3 MySub3)
set(MYLINKNAME IsLinked)
message("Sub1: " ${MYNAME1} " " ${MYNAME2} " " ${MYNAME3} " " ${MYLINKNAME})
```

sub1/CMakeLists.txt

```
message("Sub2: " ${MYNAME1} " " ${MYNAME2} " " ${MYNAME3} " " ${MYLINKNAME})
set(MYNAME2 OtherName)
```

The result is:

```
Sub1: MyName1  MySub3 IsLinked
Parent1: MySub1 MySub2  MyLinkName
Sub2: MySub1 MySub2  MyLinkName
Parent1: MySub1 MySub2  MyLinkName
```

Which means that I can transfer information using PARENT_SCOPE from sub1 to sub2. However, I would like to avoid patching packages for testing, logging, etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The actual question I derived from your words is *"How can I transfer information using PARENT_SCOPE without patching packages for testing, logging?"*. Which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Anyway, there is one more way to transfer information: `set(MY_GLOBAL_VAR <value> CACHE INTERNAL "")`. You can do this in any scope and will be visible in any scope.

Comment: @ tamas.kenez I want to transfer say the location of library include files from a standard package to my main program, and those two are in two different scopes. For me it has sense. The second idea is to be used also in the child project, i.e. I need to patch say a downloaded external package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replying to the question in your comment:

### Transferring the location of the include files from a standard package to your main program

You can find an example for this in the official `FindZLIB.cmake` module:

```
add_library(ZLIB::ZLIB UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(ZLIB::ZLIB PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

The find-module creates an imported library `ZLIB::ZLIB` and set its `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property to the location of the `zlib` include files.

Later, in your main program you invoke the find-module:

```
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
```

add your main target:

```
add_executable(mymain main.cpp)
```

and add ZLIB as dependency:

```
target_link_libraries(mymain ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

The location of the `zlib` include files will be available in `main.cpp` but you can also query it in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
get_target_property(zlib_incl_dirs ZLIB::ZLIB INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

The same method works also for

- config-module which is like a find-module but it's shipped with the library
- child-projects:

In `main/child1/CMakeLists.txt` you can write:

```
add_library(child1 ...)
target_include_directories(child1 ... PUBLIC ... )
```

In `main/child2/CMakeLists.txt` you can write

```
add_executable(child2 child2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(child2 child1)
```

In `child2.cpp` the `PUBLIC` include directories will be added to the include path. You can also query it in your `main/child2/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
get_target_property(child1_incl_dirs child1 INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the meantime I found your package Cake. I would consider brushing it up. You probably reorganized the project, and many mistypes like Cake.cmake/cake.cmake disturbs using it. Also, a full, working elementary example would be valuable.

Comment: For a full (rather complex) working example see the [mapbox-gl-native-cmake-builder](https://github.com/tamaskenez/mapbox-gl-native-cmake-builder.git) project. But in the meantime I've found a cleaner, simpler approach to organize cmake projects with dependencies, that's why I abandoned `cake`. See [centralbuilder](https://github.com/tamaskenez/centralbuilder), it's living and documented.